# How can I get the street names (in vector layer OSM, lines) that border parcels of land (in vector layer, polygons) on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap

I have parcel data and street-level data (not in map), which I need to merge. My map contains the polygon-parcels and OSM streets - is there a way to capture the 4 or 5 streets that surround a parcel on ArcMap?

Comment: Assuming your parcels are polygons and your street date is centreline you can use Generate Near Table http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001n000000 with a suitable small distance.. you will get a table with your parcel ID an all roads that are within a distance - this is not perfect, lines that do not follow parcel boundaries will also be included. This tool requires an advanced license. If you don't have an advanced license you can buffer the parcels and intersect with the roads, the benefit of this method is that you can remove short intersections.

Comment: Hi @MichaelStimson! I actually just finished running a Spatial Join (one to many; match option: crossed by the outline of) and ended up with a pretty good attribute table of polygons (in repeating rows) that correspond to many streets around it. I wonder if you think this method is wrong? I'm just about to try your suggestion, thanks for it!

Comment: Please  [edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.  Remember to always specify the exact software release and license level within the body of the question. The [Tour] helps expain what is expected.

Comment: I would need to see your data to comment. As I understand it you have parcels (polygon) that fall short of your roads (line) so a simple spatial join is unsuitable which is why I'd buffer your parcels (or roads) and intersect the buffer and roads, this will give you a feature class with the attributes of the parcels *and* roads but will affect the parcels' geometry, remove the small sections by length or area if you buffered the roads and you have a table that matches parcels to bounding roads which can be related one-to-many to your parcels by OBJECTID.. doesn't work so well with shapefiles.

Comment: The Generate Near Table worked very well. Thank you!